# Send message to multiple servers pyzmq

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

If I have one client connect to multiple servers, and try to send a message,

```
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:5565")
socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:5566")
socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:5567")
socket.send("Hello all")
```

only one server will actually get the message. The [documentation](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/multiprocess/multiprocess.html) says that pyzmq preforms some simple load balancing across all available servers.

**Is there a way send a message to all servers, rather than just one?**

---

Background:

I am trying to control a network of raspberry pis with my computer. I need to send a message to all of them at once, but I can't use PUB/SUB model, because then they all need to respond to that message.

I have one requester (master computer) that sends a request to all of the repliers (raspberry pis), and they all reply individually. For example I could send one message asking to get the reading from a tempurature sensor, and I want all of the raspberry pis to get read a tempurature sensor and send it back.

Comment: Do you have to use pyzmq? It seems threading and socket are good enough for your issue.

Comment: You would probably be better off using PUB/SUB if you do not need a back-chatter. Multiple REQ/REP is ok, but the server needs to know the number of clients a priory or use some discovery method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PUB/SUB to send the request, and an entirely separate PUSH/PULL socket to get the answers back. The response message should probably include a field saying which Pi it has come from.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

*Use an **appropriate** Formal Communication Pattern.*

ZMQ.REQ formalism indeed expects, that the component is asking some other process, via sending a REQUEST, to do some job in response to the message. Thus the multiple exgress targets the **`.connect()`** has built a transport relation with, are served in a round-robin mode, selecting one after another, in a fair-queue-policy mode. So the component works but for a different purpose, than you are asking it to do.

### Solution

Try some more complex Formal Communication Pattern that "spreads" the message to all relevant peers ( PUB/SUB alike ) but more complex, smarter, fail-safe derived schemes, that would serve your Raspberry PI solution needs.

The greatest strength of the ZeroMQ is in that it off-loads the low-level details from you and leaves you an immense power in designing all the needed distributed scaleable Formal Communication Patterns, that you need. Forget about just the few primitives ( building blocks ) directly listed in the ZeroMQ binding. Think about your abstract message/event processing scheme and then assemble ZeroMQ elements to meet that scheme.

ZeroMQ [socket] is not a hose from A to B. It is rather an access port for dialogues with smart Formal Communication Pattern Nodes. You may benefit, that [socket] may work over many transport classes at the same time ... so your **Formal Communication Patterns** may **span** over L3-networks `[TCP:]` + go into `[IPC:]` and `[INPROC:]` process-to-process channels inside the [localhost].

All working in parallel ( well, sure - almost in parallel once inspected in lower detail )

All working in smooth co-integrated environment.

### Where to source from?

A best next step you may do for this is IMHO to get a bit more global view, which may sound complicated for the first few things one tries to code with ZeroMQ, but if you at least jump to the **page 265** of the [**Code Connected, Volume 1 [*asPdf*->]**](http://hintjens.wdfiles.com/local--files/main%3Afiles/cc1pe.pdf), if it were not the case of reading step-by-step there.

The fastest-ever learning-curve would be to **have first an un-exposed view** on the **Fig.60** *Republishing Updates* and **Fig.62** *HA Clone Server pair* for a possible High-availability approach and then go back to the roots, elements and details.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is using `PUSH/PULL` instead of `PUB/SUB`, because with `PUB/SUB` method your message may be lost if a subscriber has not been executed, but in `PUSH/PULL` method when a *Client/Sender* post a message (`PUSH`), the *Server/Getter* can get it any time with the `PULL` attribute.

---

## Here's a simple example:

Client side snippet code:

```
import zmq

def create_push_socket(ip, port):
    print('PUB')
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    zmq_address = "tcp://{}:{}".format(ip, port)
    socket.connect(zmq_address)
    return socket 

sock1 = create_push_socket('RPi-1-IP', RPi-1-PORT)
sock2 = create_push_socket('RPi-1-IP', RPi-1-PORT)
sock3 = create_push_socket('RPi-1-IP', RPi-1-PORT)

sock1.send('Hello')
sock2.send('Hello')
sock3.send('Hello')
```

Server side snippet code:

```
import zmq

def listen():
    context = zmq.Context()
    zmq_ = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
    zmq_.bind('tcp://*:6667')
    print(zmq_.recv())


listen()
```

Answer (score -1):

I just used an array of req/rep pairs. Each client has multiple req sockets and each server has one rep socket. Is this not a scalable solution? The data being sent does not require high scalability. If it does be a problem, I could work something out with pub/sub.